# MVC download data from database between two dates

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

Here is my code for download data from multiple tables in single excel sheet. how to add two dates in this code? 
This code is working perfect for download but I need to download with two dates.

Controller
These are two tables selecting all data from database using datatable

```
    Table 1

        private DataTable getTable1()
            {
                string constr = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["db_Demo"].ConnectionString;
                using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(constr))
                {
                    using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT * FROM Table1 ORDER BY ID"))
                    {
                        using (SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter())
                        {
                            DataTable dt = new DataTable();
                            cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
                            cmd.Connection = con;
                            da.SelectCommand = cmd;
                            da.Fill(dt);
                            return dt;
                        }
                    }
                }
            }

    Table 1
        private DataTable getTable2()
            {
                string constr = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["db_Demo"].ConnectionString;
                using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(constr))
                {
                    using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT * FROM Table2 ORDER BY ID"))
                    {
                        using (SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter())
                        {
                            DataTable dt = new DataTable();
                            cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
                            cmd.Connection = con;
                            da.SelectCommand = cmd;
                            da.Fill(dt);
                            return dt;
                        }
                    }
                }
            }

    public DataSet getDataSetExportToExcel()
        {
            DataSet ds = new DataSet();

            DataTable dtTable1 = new DataTable("Table1");
            dtTable1 = getTable1();

            DataTable dtTable2 = new DataTable("Table2");
            dtTable2 = getTable2();


ds.Tables.Add(dtTable1);
            ds.Tables.Add(dtTable2);
            return ds;
        }

    public ActionResult btn_Export_Click()
        {
            DataSet ds = getDataSetExportToExcel();
            using (XLWorkbook wb = new XLWorkbook())
            {
                wb.Worksheets.Add(ds);
                wb.Style.Alignment.Horizontal = XLAlignmentHorizontalValues.Center;
                wb.Style.Font.Bold = true;
                Response.Clear();
                Response.Buffer = true;
                Response.Charset = "";
                Response.ContentType = "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet";
                Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", "attachment;filename= TablesData.xlsx");
                using (MemoryStream MyMemoryStream = new MemoryStream())
                {
                    wb.SaveAs(MyMemoryStream);
                    MyMemoryStream.WriteTo(Response.OutputStream);
                    Response.Flush();
                    Response.End();
                }
            }
            return View();
        }
```

View
These are dates

```
<div>
    To: <input type="date" value="startdate" />
    From: <input type="date" value="enddate" />
</div>

<div>
    <a href="@Url.Action("btn_Export_Click", "Data")" class="btn btn-success"> Export Data</a>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming your date field in your table is called "RefDate", you could try to do the following:

```
private static DataTable GetTable(string table, DateTime startDate, DateTime endDate)
{
    string constr = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["db_Demo"].ConnectionString;
    using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(constr))
    {
        using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand($"SELECT * FROM {table} WHERE RefDate BETWEEN @startDate AND @endDate ORDER BY ID"))
        {
            var startDateParameter = new SqlParameter("@startDate", SqlDbType.DateTime);
            startDateParameter.Value = startDate;

            var endDateParemeter = new SqlParameter("@endDate", SqlDbType.DateTime);
            endDateParemeter.Value = endDate;

            cmd.Parameters.Add(startDateParameter);
            cmd.Parameters.Add(endDateParemeter );

            using (SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter())
            {
                DataTable dt = new DataTable();
                cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
                cmd.Connection = con;
                da.SelectCommand = cmd;
                da.Fill(dt);
                return dt;
            }
        }
    }
}


private static DataSet GetDataSetExportToExcel(DateTime startDate, DateTime endDate)
{

    var dtTable1 = GetTable("Table1", startDate, endDate);
    var dtTable2 = GetTable("Table2", startDate, endDate);

    var ds = new DataSet();
    ds.Tables.Add(dtTable1);
    ds.Tables.Add(dtTable2);
    return ds;
}

[HttpGet]
public ActionResult Export()
{
    return View();
}

[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Export(DateTime startDate, DateTime endDate)
{
        DataSet ds = GetDataSetExportToExcel(startDate, endDate);
        using (XLWorkbook wb = new XLWorkbook())
        {
            wb.Worksheets.Add(ds);
            wb.Style.Alignment.Horizontal = XLAlignmentHorizontalValues.Center;
            wb.Style.Font.Bold = true;
            Response.Clear();
            Response.Buffer = true;
            Response.Charset = "";
            Response.ContentType = "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet";
            Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", "attachment;filename= TablesData.xlsx");
            using (MemoryStream MyMemoryStream = new MemoryStream())
            {
                wb.SaveAs(MyMemoryStream);
                MyMemoryStream.WriteTo(Response.OutputStream);
                Response.Flush();
                Response.End();
            }
        }
        return View();
 }
```

You need to rename your view to be "Export" and adapt it to send the data in the following way:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("Export", "Form", FormMethod.Post))
{
    <div>
        <label for="startDate">From:</label>
        @Html.TextBox("startDate", "{0:dd/MM/yyyy}", 
            new { @class = "form-control date", type = "date" })

        <label for="endDate">To:</label>
        @Html.TextBox("endDate", "{0:dd/MM/yyyy}", 
            new { @class = "form-control date", type = "date" })
    </div>

    <input type="submit" class="btn btn-success" value="Export Data" />
}
```

Comment: There is error on getTable1 is that There is no argument given that corresponds to the required formal parameter 'startDate' of 'TablesController.getTable1(DateTime, DateTime)'                     DataTable dtTable1 = new DataTable("Table1");
            dtTable1 = getTable();

Comment: You need to pass your dates when you call the getTable1 date method. Be careful I made the method static, try by removing that.

Comment: I have pass dates as parameter but there is error on dataset method

Comment: Object must implement IConvertible. when I click on button

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/204873/discussion-between-usman-azam-and-isma).

Comment: when I download data from today selecting date it is not downloading but when I select date tomorrow then it is downloading today's data. what is the problem?

Comment: I think I have helped enough, hopefully you can fix that small issue now yourself or create a new question specific to that problem. Don´t forget to mark the answer as resolved if it helped to solve the problem so other users can find it. Cheers.

Comment: I know dear, you have helped enough. Thanks a lot.

Comment: If you post a new question for the other problem send me the link, I will take a look in case I can solve it.